# Mongoose unable to get _id from Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I 've a UserSchema that looks like:

```
export var UserSchema: Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt: Date,
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  tokens: [{
    access: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }]
});
```

And I 've a instance method like:

```
   UserSchema.methods.printThis =  () => {
        var user = this;
        console.log("========>>> PRINTING USER NOW");
        console.log(user);
};
```

The method `printThis` is being called from

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    var user = new User(body);

    console.log("created user as: ", user);

    user.printThis();
});
```

Below is the output:

```
created user as:  { email: 'prsabodh.r@gmail.com',
  password: '123456',
  _id: 59be50683606a91647b7a738,
  tokens: [] }
========>>> PRINTING USER NOW
{}
```

You can see that the user is getting created properly. However, when I call `printThis` method on `User` - I'm not able to print the same user back and an empty `{}` is printed. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use arrow functions (`=>`) if the calling function is explicitly setting a context (which is what Mongoose does):

```
UserSchema.methods.printThis = function() {
  var user = this;
  console.log("========>>> PRINTING USER NOW");
  console.log(user);
};
```

More info on arrow functions and their handling of `this` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

To get the `_id` value from the instance method can use `_conditions` that should work

```
UserSchema.methods.printThis = function(password) {
    var user = this;
    console.log(user._conditions['_id']);
};
```

Comment: when you call the method `generateAuthToken`? @prabodhprakash

Comment: from `router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {` In this method, I create `user` which is created successfully and then, on the instance of user I call this method.

Comment: could you update your question with `router.post('/signup'...` full code ? @prabodhprakash